# How to load .iqy file into excel as datasource

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerquery

I'm having some data from a custom build sharepoint site, which only offers me access to the content by giving me and .iqy file for each category on the site.

Opening the .iqy directly with excels works by giving me a new excel sheet, but what I want to archive here is containing 3 different categories into 1 excel sheet and also have them automatically update whenever the sharepoint site receives any updates for the 3 categories(or when I click refresh).

I've looked into excels "Data" section and also searched the web and the documentation of excel itself with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loading an .iqy file (Also known as Web Queries) into an existing Excel file can be archieved by loading the .iqy file into connections using the following steps in Excel:

1. Choose the tab "Data"
2. Click "Existing Connections"
3. Choose "Browse for More..." (This opens up a file picker)
4. Navigate to .iqy file
5. Choose where to export to (ie. table and to new or existing worksheet)

The .iqy describes how content can be fetched from a data source and therefore it supports the refresh functionality within the "Data" tab, also found in the "Connection" pane.
Whenever the data source is changed, you can use "Refresh" on the connection to update your Excel data.

To incoorporate it with Excels Data "Queries" using Power Query:

1. Pick the table where the content was loaded to
2. Choose tab "Data"
3. Click "From Table/Range"
4. Profit!